How to enable S3 transfer acceleration on presigned POST
I enabled transfer acceleration for an s3 bucket using the aws PHP sdk, I was able to create a presigned download URL that uses transfer acceleration using the following code:
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$S3_Client = new S3Client([
'version'     => 'latest',
'region'    =>'us-east-1',
'credentials' => [
        'key'    => 'Accesskey',
        'secret' => 'Secretkey',
  ],
'use_accelerate_endpoint' => True
]);

$cmd = $S3_Client ->getCommand('GetObject', [
    'Bucket' => $bucketName,
    'Key' => $fileId,
    'ResponseContentDisposition' => "attachment; filename=\"$filename\"",
]);
$expiration = new DateTime("+6 hours");
$request = $s3->createPresignedRequest($cmd, $expiration);
$downloadUrl = (string) $request->getUri();

I can see in the browser console that the generated download presigned url looks like this:
https://bucketname.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/xyzxyz
But when uploading I'm using a presigned post instead of a presigned url, in this way:
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\PostObjectV4;

$S3_Client = new S3Client([
'version'     => 'latest',
'region'    =>'us-east-1',
'credentials' => [
        'key'    => 'Accesskey',
        'secret' => 'Secretkey',
  ],
'use_accelerate_endpoint' => True
]);

 $postObject = new PostObjectV4(
    $S3_Client,
    $bucket,
    $formInputs,
    $options,
    $expires
);
$formAttributes = $postObject->getFormAttributes();
$url = $formAttributes['action'];

But in this second case even though I specified use_accelerate_endpoint I can see in the browser console that the upload URL generated by the presigned post is not taking advantage of transfer acceleration, and looks like this:
"url": https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com
Am I doing something wrong or is it just not possible to use transfer acceleration with presigned post? In the first example it is working correctly but I'm using a presigned URL, it's just the presigned post that is apparently not being accelerated.

yes you are doing something wrong, AWS S3 Transfer Acceleration is not supported for presigned POST URLs. This is a known limitation in AWS.  you need to use presigned URLs in your case for uploads instead
